# Portable C compiler for Windows on USB stick

Tags: windows, usb, portable, compile, c

I am looking for a portable **C** compiler to run from an USB stick on Windows (XP or higher).

If it's a GCC portable version, that's a plus. If it's also (optionally) a C++ compiler, that's a plus too.

I do know of [Tiny C Compiler](http://bellard.org/tcc/), but I wouldn't call it a full-featured compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just grab your personal copy of [mingw](http://www.mingw.org) and put it onto the stick.

Answer (score 1):

[Dev C++ portable](https://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/) is an excellent C,C++ compiler with an inbuilt IDE..

Comment: and it's gcc compatible...

Comment: The project is no longer available

Comment: @Sabrina, link updated. The project seems to be maintained by someone else now.